# How to compare if((sender as Grid).Background== new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)) in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, colors

How to compare   if((sender as Grid).Background== new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green)) in wpf
grid is dynamic

below is code

```
private void Grid_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
        {

            System.Windows.Media.Brush newColor = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Yellow;
            // SolidColorBrush newBrush = (SolidColorBrush)newColor;

            //   //  System.Drawing.Brush b = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush((System.Drawing.Color)new System.Drawing.ColorConverter().ConvertFromString(new System.Windows.Media.BrushConverter().ConvertToString(Colors.Yellow)));
            //// System.Windows.Media.Color imageColor =( System.Windows.Media.Color) newBrush;
            string co = null;

            if((sender as Grid).Background== new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green))

                co = "Audited";
            else if((sender as Grid).Background== new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red))
                co = "DoNotAudit";
            else if((sender as Grid).Background== new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Orange))
                co = "ReAudit";
            else if((sender as Grid).Background== new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow))
                co = "TobeAudited";
            MessageBox.Show(co);
        }


    }
```

co shows null value

Comment: You shouldn't be using the color to determine state, instead you should be using state to determine color. Isn't there anything else you can use to determine the state of the grid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not compare two different brushes, instead, get both colors and compare them:

```
var grid = sender as Grid;

if(grid != null)
{
  var background = grid.Background as SolidColorBrush;

  if(background != null)
  {
    var color = background.Color;

    if(Colors.Green.Equals(color))
    {
       co = "Audited";
    }
    else if(Colors.Red.Equals(color))
    {
      co = "DoNotAudit";
    }
    else if(Colors.Orange.Equals(color))
    {
      co = "ReAudit";
    }
    else if(Colors.Yellow.Equals(color))
    {
      co = "TobeAudited";
    }
  }
}
```

Your code implies that you are not using [MVVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) as pattern. WPF was meant to be programmed using the MVVM pattern. You may want to look it up and use it, it makes things a lot easier.

Comment: +1 for the answer, but note that WPF support MVVM and it doesn't mean you should use MVVM. And with MVVM you can use the code behind as well.

Comment: @ChamikaSandamal no, everybody can use WPF as he/she pleases. But not using MVVM (in this case the view presentation driving the logic instead of the logic driving the view presentation) is harder than it has to be. If used right, WPF is very, very powerful. If used wrong, it's nothing but a nicer looking WinForms.